# Set the active status of a user in the credentials and still return an activation message in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I wanted to find out how I would do as requested in the subject line, as the code below works fine but the user is logged in before checking the $user->Activated status.  Here is some code to illustrate:

AuthController

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if ($user->Activated) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'activated' => 'You need to activate your account to login'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Preferably I would like to do the following:

AuthController

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');

    return array_add($credentials, 'Activated', '1');
}
```

But then the only message that gets returned is "These credentials do not match our records.", instead of "You need to activate your account to login".  Also how would I update a LoginStatusId once the user is logged in, currently I do it like this:

AuthController

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if ($user->Activated) {
        $user->LoginStatusId = 1;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'activated' => 'You need to activate your account to login'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Is there a better place to set the $user->LoginStatusId once they login, or is this the best place to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Open this file `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

Add this block of code inside `postLogin`

```
// If activated is equal to 1, user allowed to login or throw an credential mismatch error

$userData = User::select('activated')->where('email', $request['email'])->first();

if ($userData->activated == 1) {
    $request['activated'] = $activated;
}

$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request); //add these code before this line
```

And add `'activated'` to getCredentials method. It will look like this:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password', 'activated');
}
```

You can check user login status anywhere just using this `Auth::user()`. No need to store login status by yourself. As example in any controller you can write this:

```
if(Auth::user()){
    // do this;
}else{
    // do that;
}
```

Comment: Hi smartrahat thanks very much for your answer, but is there a way of doing exactly what you said without modifying the AuthenticatesUsers.php vendor file as vendor files will get overridden if you upgrade Laravel?

Comment: As you are using Laravel's default authentication system, you have modify it's default Controller if any change need in authentication. Upgrading may overwrites vendor files but not sure about controllers.